# Spring ApplicationListener being destroyed after one event

Tags: java, spring-boot, events

I am trying to use an EventListener to process the data produced by another component.  Everything works fine the first time an event fires, but the EventListener is then removed from the list of listeners.

Here is the relevant part of the listener:

```
@Component
public class Listener implements ApplicationListener<CustomEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

And here are the publisher's relevant parts:

```
@Component
public class Publisher {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void start() {
        try {
            ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CustomEvent event = new CustomEvent(this, getUpdates());
                    applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
            }, 0, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

And the CustomEvent class:

```
public class CustomEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private List<Update> updates = new ArrayList<>();

    public CustomEvent (Object source, List<Update> updateList) {
        super(source);
        updates = updateList;
    }
    public List<Update> getUpdates() {
        return updates;
    }
}
```

Based on what I can tell from the debugger, it seems like the Listener bean is getting destroyed when I don't expect it to.  Any idea how to keep it around to listen for events beyond the first?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're telling that. I do note that you're creating new executors and leaking them (never shutting them down); instead, you should be creating a single executor as a field, reusing it, and calling `shutdown()` in an `@PreDestroy` method.

Comment: The start() method only gets called once on application startup.  Does the scheduleAtFixedRate() method not clean up anything it creates?

Comment: No, it doesn't; check the docs for Executors in general. Where are you getting `interval`, by the way (and while your `new Runnable()` isn't _wrong_, it's unnecessarily cumbersome since we have lambdas and you could replace the whole thing with `() -> applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new CustomEvent(this, getUpdates()));`).

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback.  Interval is just an integer value I am reading from the config file. I omitted that part of the code as it is working fine, and would have made the post unnecessarily long.